# the value of C enumeration type using typedef

Tags: c, typedef, enumeration

Do you know the result of ALL_MODULE ?
 
and do you know in which book describe this situation ?
 
Thanks a lot. :)

```
typedef enum
{
  MODULE0,
  MODULE1,
  MODULE2
}MODULE_TAG;

#define ALL_MODULE (MODULE_TAG-1)
```

Comment: The result will be a syntax error.  What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: eg.  MODULE_TAG mod_x;          if(mod_x == ALL_MODULE){...}; // it seems that when mod_x equal MODULE0, or MODULE1, or MODULE2, that if statement is all true.

Comment: `mod_x == ALL_MODULE)` it isn't become all be equal. because if A=B and B=C then A=C (B:all,A:MODULE0,C:MODULE1), but A(MODULE0) != C(MODULE1).

Answer (score 4):

I think the definition was probably a little different:
`#define ALL_MODULE ((MODULE_TAG)-1)`

E.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef enum
{
  MODULE0 = 1,
  MODULE1 = 2,
  MODULE2 = 4
}MODULE_TAG;

#define ALL_MODULE ((MODULE_TAG)-1)

int main(){
    MODULE_TAG all = ALL_MODULE;
    MODULE_TAG amod = MODULE1;

    if(amod == MODULE1){
        printf("amod equal MODULE1\n"); 
    }
    if(amod != MODULE1){
        printf("amod not equal MODULE1\n"); 
    }

    if(all & MODULE0){
        printf("all has MODULE0\n");
    }
    if(all & MODULE1){
        printf("all has MODULE1\n");
    }
    if(all & MODULE2){
        printf("all has MODULE2\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *Now* I get it; you're *casting* the value `-1` to type `MODULE_TAG` and assuming that `all` has all bits set.  Duh.  I R slow today.  Might help to visually separate that a bit - `#define ALL_MODULE ( (MODULE_TAG) -1 )`

Comment: @BLUEPIXY, yeah, you're right... the guy want to casting the value -1 to type MODULE_TAG...

Answer (score 1):

An enum typedef doesn't have a value. Using ALL_MODULE in an expression will result in a compilation error.

Comment: @celiazou0914 gcc compiler gives compiler error ")" expected before "-".